# version in npm package.json (resolved, the version was changed not in my attention)

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I work with `grunt` to run its tasks and therefore I need to install npm.

In my `package.json` I had `version` param wit value `0.2`.

```
{
  "author": "Author name",
  "name": "package",
  "version": "0.2",
}
```

When I had used

```
run npm install
```

I had **no errors**

I changed the `version` to `1.0` recently, and now **have errors**

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "semver"
npm ERR! node v0.12.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1

npm ERR! Invalid version: "1.0"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

But even I change the `version` to `0.2` it does't work

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1

npm ERR! Invalid version: "0.2"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

But **It works** when I set version value with **`0.0.0`** format. Works fine `version: 0.2.0`.

What the problem was with my npm?

Comment: According to semver you should have the version as `x.y.z` format

Comment: Given that npm versions are semver, which are number, dot, number, dot, number, I'm not sure I believe you when you say that 0.2 worked...

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I got a new project last Mon and had 0.2. With some lucky I installed it

Comment: That's not so much "lucky", that's "I did things wrong". Just use proper npm versioning next time =) An `npm init` will create a package.json with all the values in legal format, including a version starting at 0.0.0, and `npm version patch` will bump up your release *and* create a git tag that you can push up, so everything'll just work.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the docs - https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#version - the version should be parseable by `node-semver`. It has to be a semver that follow the general format of `major.minor.patch`. It working with your initial version of `0.2` would not be possible, and must have been a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :- check Node version -->Open power shell and type node ,it will provide followed interface(on windows environment ) ,

PS C:\Users\Nuwana\Desktop\test> node
Welcome to Node.js v14.15.4.

Step 2 :- edit package.json file with relevant NodeJS version as like followed ,

{
"name": "test",
"version": "14.15.4",
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.17.1"
}
}

Step 3 :-now ,Try with  npm install command to fix error